# What is a good API to find the latitude and longitude of a zip code?

Tags: api, geocoding, latitude-longitude

Anyone know of a good free API to get the coordinates of a zip code? What I am currently using is

```
http://forecast.weather.gov/zipcity.php?inputstring=00000
```

But this is not a real API and is subject to change. I do not need exact locations, the purpose of this information is to find sunrise / sunset times.

Comment: A good question to ask yourself is where in the zip code is the measurement taken.  What is the business need for this information?

Comment: I don't care where, this is for the purpose of finding sunrise and sunset times, so it doesn't have to be exact.

Comment: ok. that makes sense.   What kind of data volume to you expect?

Comment: Probably a thousand a day, not too much.

Comment: you can use https://www.thezipcodes.com

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should take a look at the [Google API.](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/)

Comment: This appears good, I will look into it further

Comment: Keep in mind that you have to show a Map when querying into that API or you'll break the TOS.

Answer (score 8):

Since I just needed to geocode a bunch of addresses and store it in the DB, I could not use the Google API as it'd be a TOS violation. Also I was looking for batch processing if possible. My search lead me to 2 APIs.

The first API was from [MapQuest](http://open.mapquestapi.com/geocoding/). It was easy enough to sign up for a key and start using the service. The problem with the free version is, sometimes, you get back blank co-ordinates for addresses. Apparently the enterprise version does not have this issue. Alas, I had to can this as it does not suit my needs.

The second gem I stumbled upon is from the [United States Census Bureau](http://geocoding.geo.census.gov/geocoder/). It provides REST interface for API access and there is no need for an API key. So far in my tests, I've had a match returned for all my queries. My only concern here is I see no verbiage about usage limits etc. Here is a link to the documentation: http://geocoding.geo.census.gov/geocoder/Geocoding_Services_API.pdf

Comment: it's a gem! WTG USCB

Comment: Here's an example request: https://geocoding.geo.census.gov/geocoder/locations/onelineaddress?address=4600+Silver+Hill+Rd%2C+Suitland%2C+MD+20746&benchmark=9&format=json

Answer (score 1):

I've had success using [Yahoo Placefinder API](http://developer.yahoo.com/geo/placefinder/).

You can also use Google Map's API, but I believe that using that comes with certain requirements to embed map data into your site as well.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

    $zipcode=$_POST('zipcode');

    $url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=".$zipcode."&
            sensor=false";

    $details=file_get_contents($url);

    $result = json_decode($details,true);

    $account_lat=$result['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lat'];

    $account_long=$result['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lng'];

    echo "Latitude :" .$account_lat;

    echo '<br>';

    echo "Longitude :" .$account_long;
```

?>

Comment: API key is missed here, man.

Comment: The time when this answer was drafted, it doesn't require any API key. Also, this was a working solution from my project code which I've posted here. You can check the posting date man.

Comment: @NaserNikzad There might be some changes/updates done from Google in the last 5-6 years, which you have to check.

Comment: you are right, sorry for my tone.